# Push to GitLab repository within CI server (deploy keys)

Tags: git, permissions, jenkins, tagging, gitlab

GitLab has this nice 'deploy keys' feature useful for CI servers to have read and pull access to a repository as they usual don't need more than that. However, I need to create and push a tag to the repository to tag each release that is built from the 'master' branch.

To be more specific, I have a Jenkins job that will build a release version from the 'master' branch every time a build is triggered. If the job is successful, I want to tag the 'master' branch HEAD with the release number for future reference.

I believe I can't do this using the 'deploy keys' feature. So how do I go about and do this? I'm not sure I can create an extra user, just for this, and give him access to the project... Cause every user with GitLab access is tied to LDAP.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update 2017: since GitLab 8.16 (January 2017), and [issue 1376](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/1376), you now can add deploy keys with write-access.

[image: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/uploads/7bb8e205515a77baa9973a1b33455487/image.png]

---

Original answer (2013): It is right a deploy key don't (and won't) have write access to a project (as mentioned in [issue 2134](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/2134)).

That leaves you with:

- creating an LDAP generic account (if those accounts are authorized in your organization)
- creating a dummy account in a separate LDAP server (but the [gitlab omniauth-ldap](https://github.com/gitlabhq/omniauth-ldap/blob/master/lib/omniauth/strategies/ldap.rb) doesn't support multiple LDAP declaration).

Comment: Would it work if I created a separate SSH key (just not to mix it with my own) and added it to everyone's account (everyone who should have access to that project, that is). That way, if I ever leave and my account gets deleted, it would keep working... Or this will not work?

Comment: @RicardoAmaral it could, but that would involve sharing a private ssh key, which is a big no-no. *Especially* for an account with *write* access.

Comment: Yes, I know. That's why I went about creating a separate one from my own. One that would be shared *only* with the development team, the ones responsible for setting the Jenkins system. Another issue I see with this is that pushing with this SSH key will associate the commit to one of the developers and it would be better if it was from a "Jenkins CI" user or something like that, to distinguish them.

Comment: @RicardoAmaral I agree (hence the suggestion for a generic LDAP account for Jenkins)

Comment: We do the same. We have a `svcjenkins` account in LDAP (the `svc` prefix denotes _service accounts_) and this user is a member of all groups with a _Developer_ permission

Comment: Deploy keys have write access now.

Comment: @jasdefer Thank you. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: No problem, but I am not sure, if you can push with this write access.