# Are gitlab deployment keys read only?

Tags: gitlab

Are gitlab deployment keys read only?
I need to clone on ci server using a deployment key and then push the tag created by the ci process.
is that possible using a deployment key?

Comment: I have updated [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20425380/6309): GitLab 8.16 (January 2017) now has deploy keys with write access!

Answer (score 4):

> **Edit2:** This change currently has a sideeffect, as there are no users on deployment keys.  So you will find some ugly messages like `ERROR -> POST-RECEIVE: Triggered hook for non-existing user`.  The cache-invalidation (and possibly other things) are therefor not handled on write pushes through deployment-keys, which is a bit ugly.  `bundle exec rake cache:clear RAILS_ENV=production` is your friend until I can find a way to fix that (see link to GitHub below) - and please remember, that clearing the Redis-cache logs out all users, too.

Here is a short workaround to archive following on a per-key basis:

- Make `My SSH keys` readonly.  This allows to add machines with readonly access to all repos of an account.  Good if you work with trainloads of `git` subprojects.
- Make Deploy-Keys read-write on developer level.
- Make Deploy-Keys read-write on master level.

This is archived by prepending the key's title with some special characters:

- `*` to make a `My SSH keys` readonly
- `!` to make Deploy-Keys read-write
- `!!` to make Deploy-Keys master (write to protected branches)

So instead naming the key "My global key" you name it "* my global readonly key" etc.

```
diff --git a/lib/api/internal.rb b/lib/api/internal.rb
index ed6b50c..ce350b1 100644
--- a/lib/api/internal.rb
+++ b/lib/api/internal.rb
@@ -30,7 +30,11 @@ module API


         if key.is_a? DeployKey
-          key.projects.include?(project) && DOWNLOAD_COMMANDS.include?(git_cmd)
+return false unless key.projects.include?(project)
+return true if DOWNLOAD_COMMANDS.include?(git_cmd)
+return true if key.title.start_with? '!!'
+return false if project.protected_branch?(params[:ref])
+key.title.start_with? '!'
         else
           user = key.user

@@ -42,6 +46,7 @@ module API
                      then :download_code
                    when *PUSH_COMMANDS
                      then
+return false if key.title.start_with? '*' # VAHI 2014-02-09
                      if project.protected_branch?(params[:ref])
                        :push_code_to_protected_branches
                      else
```

**Edit1:** This patch now is available as `cherry-pick` on GitHub, see https://github.com/hilbix/gitlabhq/wiki

**Edit3:** You probably want following workaround, too, in case you push through a deployment key.  This is not perfect, as it does not trigger all those hooks, but it invalidates the caches such that the web pages no more show stale data:

```
diff --git a/app/workers/post_receive.rb b/app/workers/post_receive.rb
index 6416aa6..2fe98d4 100644
--- a/app/workers/post_receive.rb
+++ b/app/workers/post_receive.rb
@@ -26,6 +26,8 @@ class PostReceive

     unless user
       log("Triggered hook for non-existing user \"#{identifier} \"")
+      project.ensure_satellite_exists
+      project.repository.expire_cache
       return false
     end
```

There still is are some problems left:

A minor one, you cannot use the same key on the account level and on the deploy level at the same time.  So for keys which only have read-only access on a global basis (which probably is the default key used), you need a second special "push only" key, which allows push access to the repos.

**Edit3:** And the major one that deployment keys do not have a user attached, so that all the convenience things do not work.  If this is a problem for you the only way is, for each SSH key create a dummy-user, and add it to the group/project and give this dummy-users the correct permissions.

Complete example under Linux for a test repo at `git@gitlab.example.com:root/test.git`

- Apply above patch to GitLab
- Restart GitLab to read in the new code
- Add your `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` to GitLab Admin under `My SSH keys` and name it `* my readonly key` (or something different, starting with `*`).
- Verify, that following works: `git clone git@gitlab.example.com:root/test.git`
- Verify, that following fails on the `git push` step:

  ```
  cd test
  date > DATE.tmp
  git add DATE.tmp
  git commit -m testing
  git push
  ```
- Create a second SSH key `~/.ssh/id_push`: `ssh-keygen -b 4096 -f ~/.ssh/id_push`
- Add `~/.ssh/id_push.pub` as Deploy-Key to repo `root/test.git`.  Name it `! my push key` (or something different, starting with `!`)
- Add following to `~/.ssh/config`

  ```
  Host gitlab-push
          Hostname gitlab.example.com
          User git
          IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_push
  ```
- Add this target to your cloned repo:
  `git remote add to gitlab-push:root/test.git`
- Verify following works: `git push to master`

## Notes:

I used copy+paste to insert the patch.  It is likely it will not apply cleanly.  Sorry.

Yes, this is really a very crude hack which should not make it into the mainline.  The correct implementation would be to have a flag in the database which does this, such that you can edit it through the GUI.

For deploy keys this "key-level"-flag should be in the interesection table between key and project.  And in the non-deploy-key variant it should be on the key itself.  Perhaps this field can then act as a `default` value when adding a deploy key to another project and record the last usage of such key.

Unfortunately I am not able to implement this properly myself as I lack the knowledge how to add the necessary elements to the GUI, sorry. ;(

Comment: Interesting hack. +1. My answer only mentions "the official rule", but your hack could work.

Comment: You are right and I don't expect "the official rule" to change as doing it properly will be much more complicated.  Luckily the power of Open Source is at our side and the hack really is small compared to what it does.

Comment: Note: This "fix" triggers some problem in GitLab: `ERROR -> POST-RECEIVE: Triggered hook for non-existing user`.  Apparently `app/workers/post_receive.rb` needs a user, but deployment-keys do not have any.  This then forgets to flush the cache for the repo, because the non-user-related maintainance is bundled with the user action.  Actually I consider doing things this way a programming bug - will update my patch soon.

Answer (score 3):

Update 2017

[GitLab 8.16 (January 2017)](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#8160-2017-01-22) does introduce **deploy keys with write-access**!
[Merge Request 5807](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/merge_requests/5807)

> Now with ability to add write-access on deploy key, we can build packages like releases, makes the tag (through CI) and prepare the next release, and of course push both of them commits to git repository

Update Feb. 2021 and [GitLab 13.9](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2021/02/22/gitlab-13-9-released/#allow-deploy-keys-to-push-to-protected-branches)

> ### Allow Deploy Keys to push to protected branches
>
> Prior to GitLab 12.0, Deploy Keys with write access could push commits to protected branches.
>
> Support for this was removed due to security concerns, but many users still requested it, as they were using it to ensure that only users with Deploy Keys could push to their repositories.
>
> It also eliminates the need to use a service user or machine user, which ties up a license for any team that wants to allow Deploy Keys to push to protected branches just for this use case.
>
> We are excited to announce that we resolved this issue and now Deploy Keys can push to protected branches once more while abiding by security best practices. By moving towards an isolated permission model for Deploy Keys, users can now select Deploy Keys to link to protected branches directly from the settings page on protected branches.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/13_9/deploy_keys.png -- Allow Deploy Keys to push to protected branches]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/protected_branches.html#allow-deploy-keys-to-push-to-a-protected-branch) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/30769).

---

Original answer 2013:

Last time I checked (in "[Push to GitLab repository within CI server (deploy keys)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17917027/6309)", **no**, you don't have the right to use a deploy key to push to a repo.

> I think giving deploy keys push access is misguided. It solves the problem on the wrong end.
>
> When you have to hot patch production systems (while running?) and push changes back you are probably doing it wrong.
> Changes should always flow from the development to the production system (this should be automated!).
> Make your `dev` env as similar to your `production` env as possible (use VMs or dedicated dev/staging servers) and write tests (really do!).

---

[Litmus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1243123/litmus) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20424814/are-gitlab-deployment-keys-read-only/20425380?noredirect=1#comment30685024_20425380), and I agree with him:

> not just in GitLab, even on Bitbucket, Github etc.: **deploy keys are readonly**.
> Given that deploy keys are used to deploy on production, it should be a oneway flow. Code should go from DVCS to production but never the other way.
> Also production servers should have as less privilege as possible... that is a security best practice.
> CI runs in test environment.
> Never use same keys for production and test. That will be a disaster

---

[Curt J. Sampson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/107294/curt-j-sampson) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20424814/are-gitlab-deployment-keys-read-only/20425380?noredirect=1#comment85591021_20425380):

> There are other uses for deploy keys that don't relate to deployment.
>
> For example, if you need to mirror a repo from elsewhere into your own GitLab, you likely want your mirror script to push to your GitLab using a deploy key rather than someone's personal key.

---

Note, from [GitLab 13.5](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2020/10/22/gitlab-13-5-released/#configuration-option-to-allow-deploy-keys-to-push-to-protected-branches) (October 2020):

> ### Configuration option to allow Deploy Keys to push to protected branches
>
> In release 12.0, we updated Deploy Keys so that keys with write access could no longer push commits to protected branches. As a workaround for this limitation, some users removed access restrictions to the master branch, leaving it unprotected and allowing all developers to push to master.
>
> This increases security risks, so in order to provide a better option we have decided to re-enable the previous behavior through a configuration setting.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/#deploy-keys) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/30769).

Comment: I disagree on the point that I find absolutely useful and correct for a ci server to be able to tag after than a specific condition has been reached.

Comment: @AndreaCampolonghi I do agree with you, I merely pointed out why those deploy key aren't currently considered for write access.

Comment: Well that is really a shame even if we have a centralized machine that makes deployment to remote hosts via capistrano so I guess we could create a gitlab user for the user running the ci server jobs. We will see and decide. Is there a place where we can submit a feature request?

Comment: @AndreaCampolonghi yes: https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues or  https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-shell/issues

Comment: @Litmus I do agree with you. And I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: @Litmus Honestly I do not get your point. We do not NEVER git pull on a production server and we should NEVER share a key of a production server. We use a proper CI server that builds for testing, staging and production and takes care of delivering the build inside our VPN. Btw this is not the point here. What is useful is just being able to TAG a repo and push that tag back from automated process. This does not mean giving the key the commit right but just the TAGGING ability. And btw guthub deploy keys are read/write....

Comment: Please note that on GitHub deploy keys are not readonly.  I know this because all my pushes go through deploy keys, as global ssh keys are much too powerful (consider `git push -f`) from a security point of view.  Read: Account-wise ssh keys are a security misconception.  Period.  Hence it is good to have deployment keys, which can only be used on a single project, to push against that and be unable to harm other repos.

Comment: There are other uses for deploy keys that don't relate to deployment. For example, if you need to mirror a repo from elsewhere into your own GitLab, you likely want your mirror script to push to your GitLab using a deploy key rather than someone's personal key.

Comment: @CurtJ.Sampson Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 1):

Not just in `GitLab`, even on `Bitbucket`, `Github` etc. deploy keys are readonly.

Given that deploy keys are used to deploy on `production`, it should be a oneway flow. Code should flow from DVCS to `production` but never the other way.

Also `production` servers should have as less privilege as possible... that is a security best practice.

And most often there is a need to share deploy keys with non-developers, or automation tools. Making them readonly (at least) ensures that an unauthorized person does not screw up with the code base (of course git lets you recover almost everything, but isn't prevention better than cure?)

CI runs in `test` environment. Never use same keys for `production` and `test`. That will be a disaster.

Comment: `GitHub` deploy keys are read/write.  For security reasons it is an absolute no-go to allow access to just everything for each SSH key which is allowed to push.  Think you have 100 different development-VMs with 20 Devs each which need to push to `GitLab`. The policy says, that a private key must not be stored in a second VM for isolation reasons.  This means you have to create 2000(!) dummy `GitLab` users because you cannot add the 5 needed `ssh` keys to each repo, only because deploy keys are read-only so they cannot be used for that purpose like on `GitHub`.  WTF?

Comment: And BTW Bitbucket deploy keys are only [readonly because of greed](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/8873/extend-deployment-keys-to-allow-both-read), so I don't see any argument why GitLab is sticking out by keeping them RO (not configurable as in GitHub) just for the sake of not making them RW.