# What are public keys in GitLab?

Tags: gitlab

In my project's settings I see this:

Public deploy keys available to any project (15)

```
Rewind
CFMM Ansible Deployment
LRM Puppet Test
gitlab-runner (lion)
deploy@jasmine
deployer@stridsberg.nu
test-server
gitlab-runner
kijkmijnhuis@SensioLabsInsight
```

And many more... what are these things for? I know that if I enable one, that key then could clone my repo... but why are these things showing to me? Is there any benefit?

Answer (score 1):

See "[Deploy Keys](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ssh/README.html#deploy-keys)":

> Deploy keys allow read-only or read-write (if enabled) access to one or multiple projects with a single SSH key pair.
>
> This is really useful for cloning repositories to your Continuous Integration (CI) server. By using deploy keys, you don't have to setup a dummy user account.

I use them with Jenkins: easy to setup, easy to revoke if needed.

And I use a [read-*write* deploy key](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20425380/6309) for a maven release task to be able to push back to any repo where that key is deployed.

Comment: Would you know the difference between "Privately accessible deploy keys" and "Publicly accessible deploy keys" ? It seems that all the keys that I add go to the "Privately accessible" category (visible below the input fields). The current [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/) is not clear.

Comment: @GabrielDevillers From what I can read, a  public deploy key is one that has been added as a Global Shared Deploy key. If not, it remains "private".

Comment: @VonC but what is the benefit if I enable a public key? Is this mainly for open source projects? as an owner of a private repo I would NEVER EVER enable one of these, right? I was wondering too why they show up, because I never set them up. I see those exact 15 keys too.

Comment: @Christoph Yes, for a private project, you would not enable a public deployment key.